Postgres Parameter log_min_duration_statement
What does the time reported by the parameter log_min_duration_statement in postgres include? Parsing, planning, executing? I am sure of that. Is also client time included? Especially network latency?

The statement is logged as soon as it is completed, that is, after execution is completed and the data have been sent to the client. Note that PostgreSQL only sends the result, it does not wait until the client receives it.
